# How do i add a form to blog post detail?

Tags: django, django-forms

So I Have a small django blog project. i have successfully built a blog post views and a blog post detail view. but i want to add a small form in the post detail page; so whenever you add a new post, a new form would be made in the detail page.i know how to make forms in general. please help me with the code

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or tried looking anything up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `ModelAdmin.get_form()` and `ModelAdmin.get_fields()` and return a different set of fields once the object is created

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class CustomBlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Note that this is a custom field, not in the Blog Model
    additional_field = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'additional_field']

class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
      if obj and obj.pk:
          return ['name', 'description', 'additional_field']
      return ['name']   

   def get_form(self, request, obj, **kwargs):
      if obj and obj.pk:
          return CustomBlogForm
      return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs) 


admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields

Comment: I want a simple form that users could fill them in the detail post. Would this work for that?